# Turning a Semi-colon Separated string into individual rows

Tags: sql, split

I am attempting to convert a column called "Required Attendees" into individual rows using Outlook Calendar data. The data is structured as such:

| Subject | Required Attendees |
| --- | --- |
| Orientation Day | Doe;John;Smith;Mary;Lannister;Tyrion;The New Hire Training Team |

into

| Subject | Required Attendees |
| --- | --- |
| Orientation Day | Doe John |
| Orientation Day | Smith Mary |
| Orientation Day | Lannister Tyrion |
| Orientation Day | The New Hire Training Team |

If it makes it easier, "The New Hire Training Team" can be skipped all together. The individual names are most important.

I've tried using a SPLIT function using semicolon as the delimiter. However, since there's a semicolon between first and last name, the output has been first name as one row, last name as the second row, etc. We also have email groups such as "The New Hire Training Team" that are added to meetings which I think may throw things off.

Comment: There aren't any unambiguous rules that can be used for this. What if someone has three names? What if a valid name has a space in it? Also please tag the RDBMS and actually post the code that you tried.

Comment: This is going to be really tricky, maybe impossible without more data for context. Because if you were lucky enough to only have first and last names, two and only two and always two. You could just remove every other semicolon. Still a hassle but doable. But since you can have group names with only one token that rule goes out the windows. Doesn't matter if they can be ignored, you need a way to identify strings that are group names in order to ignore them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad